# Windows Explorer error messages?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7.5, webdav, windows-explorer

I'm wondering where Windows Explorer gets it's error messages from. *My situation* is quite specific, in that I'm using a custom WebDAV implementation, but the question I think could apply more broadly (any mapped drive).

So let's say I've got a mapped drive to my WebDAV share. I open the mapped drive window in Windows Explorer and from there I try and create a new folder. Now in my custom WebDAV implementation, I'm looking for the `MKCOL` WebDAV verb which creates folders, and in this case, I want to prevent the folder from being created. So I'm returning a 400 (Bad Request) back as the HTTP response.

The problem is, now matter how I handle this, Windows Explorer will pop up an error message that says:

> File Too Large. The file '<%1 NULL:NameDest>' is too large for the
>   destination file system.

What *file* is too large when the request is attempting to create a *folder*?

What I'm trying to figure out is where Windows Explorer got that? I can see all the details of how I'm handling the response using Fiddler (for example I can return custom exception details in the 400 response), so how does it connect my 400 to the message I'm getting above? Is there any way I can format the HTTP Response so that Windows Explorer will take the details I provide and use them in the error message?

Comment: Well. Why do you return something unspecific like that? Why 400?

Comment: 400 was just an example. I was really just curious as to how Windows Explorer determines what error message to show. I've got a custom WebDAV implementation, and it would be nice to pop up custom error messages from Windows Explorer if something goes wrong.

Comment: I had the same issue.  I found that a 501 reply (Not implemented) seemed to create the most appropriate error message in Windows Explorer.  The choices are pretty terrible, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explorer treats `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` as "file too large" since that's how some file systems report that error condition.

Answer (score -1):

Please start the command prompt (cmd.exe) with admin rights [1] and run sfc [2]:

sfc.exe /scannow

Comment: This question is about an intentional error that is thrown from a WebDAV implementation and how to modify the error message that the user sees displayed.  There is no problem with the file system.